# SQL select rows based on 2 col criteria in a separate table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish to select some rows from a table based on values from another table:
Table1 (wish to select from here) 
Columns Date, Name, Pay

Table2 (contains a 'list' that determines what is selected from Table1)
Columns Date, Name

The query I wish to write is to:
Select Date,Name,Pay from Table1 where Date,Name is present in Table2

I got as far as being able to do it on one value

```
SELECT Date,Name,Pay FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Name IN (Select Table2.name from Table2)
```

but Im stuck with how to add the date qualifier. The names in either table are not unique, what makes them unique is the date and name combination.

Comment: You can use joins

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question clearly, you want to apply `join`

```
select t1.Date,t1.Name,t1.Pay FROM Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 
ON t1.Name = t2.Name and t1.Date = t2.Date
```

Answer (score 2):

The generic SQL solution uses `exists`:

```
Select Date, Name, Pay
from Table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.date = t1.date and t2.name = t1.name);
```

This will not match values in table 2 if they are `NULL`.  For that, you would need a `NULL`-safe comparison operation.  The ANSI standard is `is not distinct from`.

Some databases support `in` with tuples.  In those databases, you can write:

```
Select Date, Name, Pay
from Table1 t1
where (t1.date, t1.name) in (select t2.date, t2.name from table2 t2);
```

Once again, this might have an issue with `NULL` values, depending on how you want to treat them.

Interestingly, you could extend your logic by using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT Date, Name, Pay
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.Name IN (Select t2.name from Table2 t2 where t2.date = t1.date);
```

Although this does what you want, I think the previous two approaches are clearer in their intent.

I should note that you could use a `join` for this.  However, that would return duplicate values if you had duplicates in `table2`.  For that reason, I prefer the `exists` or `in` methods, because these have no risk of duplicating values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alias  (and instead of subquery  a join ) for a more easy vision  of your related  table

```
SELECT a.Date, a.Name, a.Pay 
FROM Table1 a
inner join  Table2 b on a.name = b.name
```

in this case date is obtain from table1, changing the alias  or addingi both column if you need more